# Why does plotting a LinearRegression from sklearn make a crazy graph?

Tags: multiple-regression, scikit-learn

I've seen a couple of posts on how to make a simple graph that looks something like this:

[image]

The code for this would be as follows:

```
# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Plot outputs
plt.plot(X_test, regr.predict(X_test), color='red',linewidth=3)
```

I've been working on building a similar thing but using the [USA_Housing dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/vedavyasv/usa-housing) from Kaggle.

My code is as follows:

```
# plot the graph
plt.scatter(X_test[0], y_test, color = "black")

plt.plot(X_test[0], y_hat)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

`X_test[0]` is just one of the independent variables (income).

Shouldn't this just make a simple line through the prediction points?

R-squared is around 91 so the fit is good, but I guess I'm confused as to why it would look like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyplot defaults to `'-'` for linestyle argument, which means a line that connects through all of the dots, so to produce a scatter plot, whose linestyle are data points instead write

`plt.plot(X_test[0], y_hat, '.')`

Answer (score 2):

Generally plotting functions connects the points that are consecutive *in the array*. So, first sort those points and then plot.